# Where are examples of Interspersed repeats?

Tags: genetics, dna, sequence-analysis

Interspersed repeats are often defined as repetitive sequences dispersed throughout the genome.

However such definition (IMO) does not exclude Tandem Repeat Sequences.

So I started to search for examples of such sequences.

After checking many Bioinformatics and Genetics books, I found many examples of Microsatellites and Minisatellites. However, I couldn't find any examples of Interspersed Repetitive DNA out there, in any of its variants (LINEs: L1, L2, L3, SINEs, etc.).

So my conclusion is Interspersed Repeats DNA Sequence looks like any other type of repeat (such as STRs or Minisatellites), the only real difference is they are flanked by Open Reading Frames (ORFs 1 and 2 for LINEs) or specific tandem duplications (like GC for SINEs)

Do anyone have one or two examples of concrete Interspersed Repeat DNA Sequences?